# Follow member system php

Tags: php, sql, relationship

I'd like to create a "follow user" system using php and mysql. I'm developing a website that requires this functionality and would love to have some help with the script coding and table structure - I'm stuck.

I'd like user1 to be able to "follow" user2 without having to confirm friendship. Once user1 clicks the "follow button", I'd like a notification to be sent to user2 saying that user1 has added them to their friends. this is just the first part of what I'd like the functionality of my website to be, but this would help me out so much.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck ? Do you have some sample code to show us how far you've gone ?

Comment: @sjobe i can't seem to figure out how to get both user1's id and user2's id and add them to my "friends" table into "user_id" and "friend_id". i have $id=$_SESSION['id'] which is "user_id"(also user1) at the beginning of my code, but i'm not sure how to get user2's id.

Answer (score 3):

Simplified answer in very "low-level" (in sense of being very easy - and so not really field-tested ;p)

table `user_following` structure could be like:

- **followerUserID** - pk; userID of user who wants to follow `followingUserID`
- **followingUserID** - pk; userID of user who will being followed by `followerUserID`
- timestamp - could be used to track when `followerUserID` added `followingUserID` to be followed by him

php code (as mentioned: VERY simplified)

```
<?php
// ...

class UserRelation extends User {
  /**
   * follow userID $userID and tell $userID that someone follows him
   *
   * @param int $userID
   * @return void
   **/
  public function followUserID($userID) {
    // send a message that $this->userID follows $userID
    Message::sendFollowUserNotification($this->userID, $userID);

    // add to database
    $this->setFollowingUser($userID);
  }

  /**
   * adds it to database
   *
   * @param int $userID
   * @return void
   **/
  private function setFollowingUser($userID) {
    // write to database
    Database::executeQuery("INSERT INTO user_following(followerUserID, followingUserID) VALUES (". $this->userID .", ". $userID .");
  }
}

// ...
?>
```

Be more specific if you need further help - I just can show you a basic example. The topic is far too complex to be explained in 10 minutes.

Comment: @thedom i can't seem to figure out how to get both user1's id and user2's id and add them to my "friends" table into "user_id" and "friend_id". i have $id=$_SESSION['id'] which is "user_id"(user1) at the beginning of my code, but i'm not sure how to get user2's id.

Comment: @Katie Well... It looks like you are at your very beginning of coding ;-). Well... it depends how to get user2s id :). There are hundreds of methods how to get it. Do have any code to show? Or table structure? It's hard to work without your code (especially when your experience level with PHP is not that high ;-)).

Comment: @thedom Yes, I'm a novice :( I've been learning through tutorials and I've actually gotten pretty far in my website development. I have some code - this is the action of clicking the "follow user" button.

Comment: @thedom - sorry. i pressed the enter button. i just tried entering my code, but it wouldn't let me. i'm new to using this site as well, so i'm not sure how to post my code as a comment.

Comment: @thedom i got it! i figured out how to insert user1's id and user2's id into my table!